# How to determine is a certain kind of GUI object caused event?

Tags: java, swing, events

I have a simple GUI and want to handle events from a certain specific `JComboBox` and several `JCheckBox` objects. In the code below, I first check if the event was caused by the specific combo box (called `senderId`).

If not, I want to see it was caused by ANY of several check box objects. That's the part I need help with. How do I test the `ItemEvent` object to see if it was caused by **any** check box?

```
@Override
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {        
    Object itemChanged = e.getItemSelectable();
    if (itemChanged==gui.senderId) {  // Looking for a SPECIFIC JComboBox here.     
        // Do stuff for this specific JComboBox here
    } else if(THE EVENT WAS CAUSED BY ANY JCheckBox) {
        // Do stuff for any JCheckBox
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, make that "How do I test the ItemEvent object to see if it was caused by any JCheckBox?"

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 0):

Withdraw the question. Found `instanceof`

Comment: A better approach would be 'separate listeners'.

Comment: Does that require an individual class for each listener?

Comment: Not necessarily.  You might have one listener for the combo box and another for every check box.

Comment: Sorry for being thick here (extreme newbie). But aren't combo boxes and check boxes both serviced by the `ItemListener` interface and `itemStateChanged` method? So, wouldn't a separate class be required to have different `ItemListener` (s) for these two GUI objects?

Comment: What DYM by 'separate class'?  That is pretty much what I said:- two listeners would be 2 classes (both extending `ItemListener`).

Comment: Got it. Sounds like we're saying the same thing. Thanks.